# Spring Boot Devtools: Detect automatic restart and apply configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to set properties that apply only during the automatic restarts provided by Spring Boot developer tools. Is there a way to achieve this?

In other words, is there a way for some part of my code (maybe a configuration bean or a listener) to detect that a restart is under way?

In my specific use case I want to run some SQL scripts during the regular Spring Boot application startup, but not after Devtools has triggered a restart (so that my database state doesn't change during restarts).

Comment: You could disable database initialization and manually execute the insert script. You'll then be able to add some logic that checks the database states before executing the script, thus only executing it the first time.

Comment: @alexbt yes I know the purpose of devtools. It works what it's meant for, e.g. reloading the Spring context when I recompile some class. Thanks for the idea about checking DB state. I'll keep that in mind as a "last resort" if there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

It's confusing to explain, but you'll see with the code below. When Spring-Boot starts with `devtools` in its dependencies, it first starts and then immediately restarts a first time trough `devtools`. You could dynamically add command line argument to track the restarts and change the Spring profile being used when `devtools` is restarting:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ParseException, IOException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

        String profile = "";

        //(1) Very first time - Spring Boot doesn't really load, it only kick start devtool then restarts.
        if (args.length == 0) {
            args = new String[] { "spring-boot-loaded" };
            profile = "no-devtools-yet";
        } 

        //(2) The first time the application loads with devtools
        else if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("spring-boot-loaded")) {
            args = new String[] { "spring-boot-loaded", "devtools-loaded" };
            profile = "devtools";
            Field argsField = Restarter.class.getDeclaredField("args");
            argsField.setAccessible(true);
            argsField.set(Restarter.getInstance(), args);
        } 

        //(3) This is the first restart - You don't want to re-initialized the database here
        else {
            profile = "devtools-reloaded";
        }

        new SpringApplicationBuilder() //
                .sources(App.class)//
                .profiles(profile) //
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

The sketchy part is that the `Restarter` keeps the original arguments (which would be "no-devtools-yet" in this example). So when `devtools` first starts, you need to replace the `Restarter`'s internal args